# Python or in regex and non empty result

Tags: python, regex

I need to find a substring that can take 2 different forms:

```
>>> test = '348249432'
>>> x = re.findall("([2][0][0-9]{7})|([3][0-9]{8})", test)
>>> x
[('', '348249432')]
```

How can I ask Python not to return empty string, and to only give me result where a matching could have been done ?

Comment: Use `|` in a single group, like this `r"([2][0][0-9]{7}|[3][0-9]{8})"`

Comment: it works, thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`findall` returns the captured groups, stated in the [**documentation**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group. **Empty matches are included in the result unless they touch the beginning of another match**.

You want to use alternation inside of one capturing group, and I would write this as:

```
>>> test = '348249432'
>>> re.findall("(20[0-9]{7}|3[0-9]{8})", test)
['348249432']
```